# Search for specific media types in a Wikimedia Commons category

Tags: wikimedia-commons

I'm trying to get a list of all files of a specific media type (e.g. 'video') directly in a category (not in subcategories).

I've tried with `list:categorymembers&cmtype:file` which gives me all files ,but I can't find a way to filter for specific media types.

And querying all the files and then filtering them seems overkill.

I tried for a while with `generator:search` but didn't get really far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filetype:video` to get only videos. For example:

- [The regular search](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?search=Helsingborg%20incategory%3A%22Beaches%20in%20Helsingborg%22%20filetype%3Avideo&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%22fields%22%3A%7B%22filetype%22%3A%22video%22%2C%22plain%22%3A%5B%22Helsingborg%22%5D%2C%22deepcategory%22%3A%5B%22Beaches%20in%20Helsingborg%22%5D%7D%7D&ns6=1&ns14=1)
- [API](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=search&gsrsearch=fire%20filetype%3Avideo%20incategory%3Afire&gsrnamespace=6)